# .gitignore is not ignoring files in directory

Tags: git

I am trying to get git to ignore the `.chef` directory and everything underneath it.  Here's the contents of what should be overkill in my `.gitignore`

```
/d/code/chef$ cat .gitignore
.chef
.chef/
.chef/*
.chef/**
/.chef
/.chef/
/.chef/*
/.chef/**
```

But this doesn't work:

```
/d/code/chef$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .chef/trusted_certs/chef_am_hexagonmetrology_com.crt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)? The first paragraph and the Notes section explain why it doesn't work as you think and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

See how it says "modified"? That's because it was already committed. That means that it's already being "tracked". Once a file is tracked, the gitignore no longer applies. In order to get rid of it, you can delete it, commit that delete, and then it will no longer show up.

Or as wogsland said, you can just remove the file(s) from the index using `git rm -rf --cached xxxxx`

Comment: You do NOT have to delete a file to stop git from tracking it (see my answer below).

Comment: @wogsland good point. In my experience this has been the most common way of dealing with the issue

Answer (score 2):

You were already tracking the `.chef` directory and files in it before you gitignored it. You need to stop tracking those files by

```
git rm -rf --cached .chef
```

which will remove them from tracking but not remove them from the `.chef` directory. See the [`git rm` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm/2.5.0) for complete details.